# How to make an angular directive to work only in one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

i have many controllers and i have a directive. and now i want this directive to work in only one particular controller.

Plunker Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/onDmKl?p=preview

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrlA', function($scope) {

});
app.controller('MainCtrlB', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.attr('data-zoom-image', attrs.zoomImage);
      $(element).elevateZoom();
    }
  };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#native').elevateZoom();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrlA">
    <img ng-elevate-zoom ng-src="http://s27.postimg.org/xyoknslhf/blue_bird_wallpaper_small.jpg" zoom-image="http://s27.postimg.org/v5h4f601v/blue_bird_wallpaper.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrlB">
    <img ng-elevate-zoom ng-src="http://s27.postimg.org/xyoknslhf/blue_bird_wallpaper_small.jpg" zoom-image="http://s27.postimg.org/v5h4f601v/blue_bird_wallpaper.jpg" />
  </div>
```

now i want that ngElevateZoom directive to work only in MainCtrlA.

im no expert in angular, so go easy on me ;)

Comment: Why not simply refrain from using it in the other controller?

Comment: directive is designed to be reused by all controllers, so you can limit its usage by hacking it, but that will defeat the true benefit of using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice way to structure your AngularJS application is to modularize every component, that means you create your *controllers*, *directives*, *filters*, etc. and wrap them into a **module**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['moduleA', 'moduleB']);

angular.module('moduleA', [])
  .directive('myDirectiveA', function() {})
  .controller('MyCtrlA', function($scope) {});

angular.module('moduleB', [])
  .directive('myDirectiveB', function() {})
  .controller('MyCtrlB', function($scope) {});
```